# Having ClientAbortException Not able to understand the fix

Tags: java, tomcat

I am having this exception as follows :

```
Exception in writing file. null ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:369)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:448)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:363)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:392)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:381)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at com.gtnexus.page.servlet.HttpCachePolicyFilter.doFilter(HttpCachePolicyFilter.java:173)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:107)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:761)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:448)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:363)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:785)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:127)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:598)
 at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:533)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:364) ... 75 more
```

it happens on following code :

```
private void returnFile(File file, OutputStream out) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] buf = new byte[4 * 1024]; 
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in writing file. " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            CloseUtils.close(fis, out);
        }
    }
```

OutputStream refers to ServletOutputStream where an excel is rendered, Strangely it's fix is very weird which i am not able to understand, here's the fix.

```
private void returnFile(File file, OutputStream out) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in writing file. " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            CloseUtils.close(fis, out);
        }
    }
```

You can see that the only difference is the use of 4kb buffer in case of the exception, fix having buffer size with the size of total file length itself.

Now in the case of big files using a buffer is valid, My question is, what is going on? I don't understand the cause as well as the fix of this issue which is given by me only but I don't get it how it works and why.

Can anyone please explain this so i have better justification such fix?

Comment: Could you try setting the content-length header on the response, like `setHeader("Content-length", "" + file.length());`  ?

Comment: i will try that, though i can't try it now but may i ask,why that could cause this issue, length of content should not be determined until the connection is closed or until request is processed, as this issue surely raises before this, i wonder the impact of this. and if this was the cause, it would give this exception every-time not selectively or inconsistently, but sounds like a thing a to try, i will reply ASAP after checking this.

Comment: Sure this is just a wild guess, but it is something I would try, maybe if the client side is aware of the size it could prevent it from aborting before getting all the chunks.

Comment: @Vivek "i will reply ASAP after checking this. "  I'm not sure if it's frowned-upon on SO to prompt for response from OP, but I'm wondering whatever happened with this issue?